# react-hook-form useForm executed every time on Nextjs page routing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hook-form

Hi I'm new to Nextjs(v14). I want to implement a multiple page form using react-hook-form.
However, it seems that `useForm` executed every time and `defaultValues` are set at page routing (click `<Link to=XX>`).

How to keep form data across multiple pages?

please help me.

here my code.

_app.tsx

```
  return (
    <div>
      <FormProvider>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </FormProvider>
    </div>
  );
```

FormProvider.tsx

```
export const FormProvider = ({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) => {
  const defaultValues: MyForm = {
    name: '',
    description: ''
  };

  const form = useForm({
    defaultValues,
    resolver: zodResolver(MyFormSchema),
  });

  const onSubmit = () => console.log("something to do");
  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>{children}</form>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is some global state, that is maintained across multiple pages. For this example I will use react's context API, if this does not fit your use-case you can find some other state management libraries like redux, xstate, zustand and others.

Also make sure to add "use client" to your components on the top of the file, because `useState`, `useContext` and `createContext` are only on only client side.

I did not include "use client" in my examples

First you would need to create a global context, with one global state in your form provider

```js
// FormProvider.tsx
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

const FormContext = createContext();
// Exported to be used in other components
export const useFormContext = () => useContext(FormContext);

export const FormProvider = ({ children }) => {
// Global state that will be passed down to child components
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});

  return (
    <FormContext.Provider value={{ formData, setFormData }}>
      {children}
    </FormContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Now you need to wrap your app with the `FormProvider`

```js
// You are already doing this part
//_app.tsx

  return (
    <div>
      <FormProvider>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </FormProvider>
    </div>
  )
```

Now you can use it like this. Keep in mind you will be updating the global state of the form which will change on all of your pages.

```js
// In your form component
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { useFormContext } from '../path/to/formContext';

const MyFormComponent = () => {
  // Uses the data from the global state 
  const { formData, setFormData } = useFormContext();
 // Initializes the data from the global state
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    defaultValues: formData,
    resolver: zodResolver(MyFormSchema),
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
   // You will get an event, that you can destruct here
   // but it is up to you what you wanna do here

   // Set the global state with the form submission data
   // left it as a comment 
   // setFormData(data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit)}>
      {/* Form fields or components you are using */}
    </form>
  );
};
```

Unrelated example where you can access the data from another client side component.

```js
// In another component
import { useFormContext } from '../path/to/formContext';

const SomeOtherComponent = () => {
  const { formData } = useFormContext();
};
```